# How can I get rid of 0 returning of tkinter Radiobutton?

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button, ttk

I try to develop a code for GUI with Python Tkinter. However, I faced a problem but don't understand its cause.

When I call the function with button, the `Radiobutton` always returns 0.
On the other hand, I call the function alone or within another function I can get the values.

How can I get rid of that problem?

Common Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def xyzWindow():
    global xlabel
    iWidth = int(1920/2.6)
    iHeight = int(1080/3)
    iwL = int((1920-iWidth)/2)
    ihL = int((1080-iHeight)/2)
    linWin = tk.Tk()
    linWin.title("TESTING")
    linWin.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(iWidth,iHeight,iwL,ihL))
    linWin.maxsize(iWidth,iHeight)
    linWin.resizable(False,False)
    linWin.minsize(iWidth,iHeight)

    abc = tk.IntVar()
    abc.set(0)

    def ccCom():
        xlabel.configure(text = abc.get())

    xb1 = ttk.Radiobutton(linWin, text = "1 Years", value = 1, variable = abc, command = ccCom)
    xb1.pack()

    xb2 = ttk.Radiobutton(linWin, text = "3 Years", value = 2, variable = abc, command = ccCom)
    xb2.pack()

    xb3 = ttk.Radiobutton(linWin, text = "5 Years", value = 3, variable = abc, command = ccCom)
    xb3.pack()


    linWin.mainloop()
```

First Code: (Works)

```
def main():
    xyzWindow()

main()
```

Second Code: (Doesn't Work)

```
def main():
    global xlabel
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("A WINDOW")
    root.geometry("400x400")

    xlabel = tk.Label(root, text = "")
    xlabel.pack()

    xbut = tk.Button(root, text = "CHECK", command = xyzWindow)
    xbut.pack()

    root.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: don't use `Tk` for additional windows, use `Toplevel`. You need to specify the `master` for the variable in this case: `abc = tk.IntVar(master=linWin, value=0)` (you can also immediately set the value and you don't need to call `set` right after)

Comment: Thank you so much